WhatsApp Flows Text Variable Not Rendering in Template String
I'm working with WhatsApp Flows and trying to display the total cost based on user input in a form. I have a TextInput field for the quantity, and below that, I'm trying to display a message that calculates the total cost based on the quantity entered by the user and a fixed price (in this case, 100).
Here's my code:
{
  "version": "5.0",
  "screens": [
    {
      "data": {
        "value": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "__example__": true
        }
      },
      "id": "SCREEN",
      "layout": {
        "type": "SingleColumnLayout",
        "children": [
          {
            "type": "TextInput",
            "label": "Quantity",
            "name": "number"
          },
          {
            "type": "TextHeading",
            "text": "the total cost is ${form.number * 100}"
          },
          {
            "type": "Footer",
            "label": "Complete",
            "on-click-action": {
              "name": "complete",
              "payload": {}
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "title": "Welcome",
      "terminal": true,
      "success": true
    }
  ]
}

However, instead of calculating and displaying the total cost, it's printing the string literally as:
the total cost is ${form.number * 100}
I want it to evaluate the expression and show the actual calculation based on the user's input, but I'm not sure how to get this working correctly.
I tried different ways of escaping the expression, but none seem to work.
I looked into documentation, but I couldn't find a solution specific to WhatsApp Flows.
How can I dynamically render the calculated total cost based on user input in WhatsApp Flows? How do I make sure the expression gets evaluated and the result is displayed?

Template strings are currently not supported in Flows.
If you need to calculate such values, you will need to use an endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/guides/implementingyourflowendpoint
